# Sublattices in the standard integral symplectic lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, linear-algebra, lie-groups, lattices

Let $V$ denote $\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ with its standard integral symplectic form $\omega = \sum_{i=0}^{g-1}dx_{2i} \wedge dx_{2i+1}$ (or, the homology lattice of a genus $g$ surface with its intersection pairing). It follows easily from the classification of surfaces that the group $\mathrm{Sp}(V,\omega)$ acts transitively on the indivisible vectors in $V$: any such vector in homology can be represented by a simple nonseparating loop, and any two of them are related by the action of the mapping class group since cut along it gives two homeomorphic surfaces with boundary. The same is not true of course for rank two sublattices, even symplectic ones: if $U \subset V$ has rank two, then $\Lambda^2_{\mathbb{Z}}(U) \subset \Lambda^2_{\mathbb{Z}}(V)$ is a cyclic submodule spanned by a vector $\xi$, and the determinant $\omega(\xi)$ can be any integer. However, it seems like rank two sublattices with equal determinants are related by the $\mathrm{Sp}(V,\omega)$-action.

Is that true? If so, what are the invariants for symplectic rank four sublattices, coincidence of which allows to conclude that these two sublattices are related by a symplectic matrix? For example, any rank two sublattices with determinant greater than one come from a ramified cover of genus $g$ surface over a torus via pullback on cohomology, which seems not to be true anymore if one replaces rank two by rank four and a torus by a genus two surface.

Anyway, the problem seems so classical that the answer must be contained somewhere in the classical 19th century literature on quadratic forms. I would be glad for any reference.

Comment: This is closely related to the question of defining Hecke operators acting on Siegel modular forms. Try Andrianov's books "Quadratic forms and Hecke operators" and/or "Modular forms and Hecke operators" (with Zhuravlev)